# jpa manytomany for one subclass and onetomany for second subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following model:
A class Student and super class Project which has 2 subclasses SmallProject and LargeProject. 
Only one Student can works on SmallProject but many Students works on LargeProject. 
A Student might have many Projects.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "PROJECT")
public class Project {
   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
   public int getId(){ return id;}

   /**
   Other attributes
   */
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "SMALL_PROJECT")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID")
public class SmallProject extends Project {

   @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID")
   private Student student;

   /**
   Other attributes
   */
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "LARGE_PROJECT")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID")
public class LargeProject extends Project {

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(
        name = "STUDENT_LARGE_PROJECTS",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="LARGE_PROJECT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")}
)
   private List<Student> studentList;

   /**
   Other attributes
   */
}
```

My problem is how to define the relation in Student entity. to get a list of all Project and not a list of SmallProject and a list of LargeProject.

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "STUDENT")
public class Student {

  @??
  private List<Project> projectList;

   /**
   Other attributes
   */


// This works, but i have two lists
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "studentList")
private List<LargeProject> LargeProject;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
private List<SmallProject> smallProject;

}
```

It works if define a manyTomany relation between Project and Student. But that means a SmallProject could have also many Student.

Any idea how to do it ? Thanks

Comment: Anyone can help !! Thanks